# Kibana Searches Using CSV file

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I want to search Kibana against the contents of a csv file.

I have a large data of logs that i want to search for specific parameter(destination IP) and search that parameter against a csv file containing all the ips.

Can anybody give me some referees to relevant document which might help me get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

How many IPs do you have in your CSV file? In general it sounds like a [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that would be limited to 65K terms.

If it's a long list I'm not sure if this might not be simpler to do programatically against Elasticsearch directly than pasting around large queries or many elements.

Comment: Hi @xeraa, thanks for your comment. I'll have a look at terms query. The list is not that long, its are 2K items.